# Image added to WPF canvas changes size

Tags: c#, wpf, image, wpf-controls

As part of an application, I have a canvas object `<Canvas Name="canvas"/>` into which I am trying to insert the components of a clock as follows

```
// Add Background
Image bg = new Image();
bg.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 0);
bg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/background.png", UriKind.Relative));
canvas.Width = bg.Source.Width;
canvas.Height = bg.Source.Height;
canvas.Children.Add(bg);

// Add second hand
Image hand = new Image();
hand.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 10);
hand.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/hand.png", UriKind.Relative));
canvas.Children.Add(hand);
```

The first image (bg) appears correctly but the second one (hand) appears to be scaled (original size is 5 x 61 pixels, interrogating image size after creation shows it has become 6.66 x 84.02 display units)
(bg original is 130 x 130 pixels and shows as 130.4 in display units)

All the answers to my query that I can find (StackOverflow and Google) suggest DPI setting of image but both my images are 96 DPI (according to Paint)
I have tried moving the image declarations into the XAML (not a long term solution) but this makes no difference.  I have tried changing the order in which I insert the images with no effect.  I have set the canvas width/height explicitly in the XAML - no effect.
I have set the size of the image explicitly - again no effect.

Can anybody tell me what is going on?

added: Compiled using .net 4 on windows7 64bit

**Resolved:**
Paint was reporting an incorrect DPI setting for the image.
Paint.Net gave me the correct value and by changing this to 96 DPI the problem was resolved

Comment: Is there a reason you are writing this in code instead of XAML?

Comment: Most of the settings will be dynamic.  Hands will be rotated as appropriate and second hand is optional.  Going forward I expect to have various optional components which will be decided programatically.

Comment: Added: I have just tried adding both images in XAML - Same problem

Comment: Either post your solution as an answer and accept it, or delete the question if you think it is not going to be useful to anyone else.

Comment: I have now posted solution as answer.  Will accept it as soon as my rep' allows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved: Paint was reporting an incorrect DPI.  Using an alternate paint package (Paint.net) showed the DPI was different.  Correcting this setting fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set `Width` and `Height` for the second image and this had probably caused the issue.
You can also try to disable image stretching by adding a line (this should at least not scale the image, even if the control is scaled):

```
hand.Stretch = Stretch.None;
```

**Update**: I've just noticed You've already tried setting the dimensions of the image. Try to set if in the code. I'm currently looking for another possible causes of this problem.

**Update II**: I see You've found a solution. I'm glad you've made it work :).